# Could not join CSV to shapefile using PyQGIS 3.16.6

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

```py
vlayer = QgsVectorLayer("C:/yyy.shp", "yyy.shp", "ogr")
shp_uri ='C:/yyy.shp'
shp = QgsVectorLayer(shp_uri, 'yyy.shp','ogr')
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(shp)
csv_uri="file:///C:/xxx.csv?delimiter=,"
csv = QgsVectorLayer(csv_uri, "Output","delimitedtext")
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(csv)
shpField='Piezometer'
csvField='piezometerid'
joinObject = QgsVectorLayerJoinInfo()
joinObject.joinLayerId = csv.id()
joinObject.joinFieldName = csvField
joinObject.targetFieldName = shpField
joinObject.setUsingMemoryCache(True)
joinObject.setJoinLayer(csv)
shp.addJoin(joinObject)
```

In the joined shapefile, the fields of csv were added, but with NULL values.
I have validated the `shpField` and `csvField`.
Also validated the field type for both `shpField` and `csvField`.
Is it the problem in my code or the implementation?
If yes, please tell what it is.

Answer (score 4):

You did not use setters for some content. There is maybe other remaining issues

```py
shp_uri ='C:/yyy.shp'
shp = QgsVectorLayer(shp_uri, 'yyy.shp','ogr')
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(shp)

csv_uri="file:///C:/xxx.csv?delimiter=,"
csv = QgsVectorLayer(csv_uri, "Output","delimitedtext")
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(csv)

shpField='Piezometer'
csvField='piezometerid'
joinObject = QgsVectorLayerJoinInfo()
joinObject.setJoinLayerId(csv.id())
joinObject.setJoinFieldName(csvField)
joinObject.setTargetFieldName(shpField)
joinObject.setUsingMemoryCache(True)
joinObject.setJoinLayer(csv)
shp.addJoin(joinObject)
```

To debug, you can also try to manually make the join between your 2 files.

Then, after selecting your shp in the layer tree, inspect the equivalent of your `joinObject` with the following code

```py
layer = iface.activeLayer()
joinObject = layer.vectorJoins()[0]
# Only using here method `joinFieldName` to inspect
# Use other methods listed at https://qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayerJoinInfo.html
# or by doing print(dir(joinObject))
print(joinObject.joinFieldName())
```

Comment: Thank you. It's working!!!